# How can I add a number to the current number in an input field using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use jQuery to add to a number in an input field, and update the input field with the new value. The id of the input field is "total". Here is what I have tried:

```
function addBag(){
    var bagprice = 79.99;
    var currentprice = $("#total").val();
    var newprice = bagprice + parseInt(currentprice);
    $("#total").text(newprice);
}
```

Comment: `$("#total").val(newprice);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `val()` to set the  value also, not just when you get it :

```
$("#total").val(newprice);
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function addBag(){
    var bagprice = 79.99;
    var currentprice = $("#total").val();
    var newprice = bagprice + parseInt(currentprice);
    
    $("#total").val(newprice);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="total" value='1'/>


<button onClick='addBag()'>Add Bag</button>
```

Comment: I copied your code exactly, but when I click the button the input displays "NaN". What does this mean?

Comment: I think your input is empty by default, Is it?

Comment: You are exactly right, I forgot to set it's value to 0. Thanks!